# ios 7 initWithOverlay deprecated

Tags: ios, deprecated

what is the alternative logic for this deprecated method

```
MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
polylineView.lineWidth = 3;
polylineView.strokeColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:5.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:48.0/255 alpha:1];


MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
circleView.lineWidth = 2;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the documentations of `MKPolylineView` and `MKCircleView`:

```
// Prefer MKPolylineRenderer
MKPolylineRenderer *polylineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
polylineView.lineWidth = 3;
polylineView.strokeColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:5.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:48.0/255 alpha:1];

//Prefer MKCircleRenderer
MKCircleRenderer *circleView = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
circleView.lineWidth = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire set of classes around MKOverlayPathView was deprecated in favor of MKOverlayRenderer classes like:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathRenderer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayPathRenderer